# Asynctask with network operation and another Asynctask task issue

Tags: java, android, multithreading, http, android-asynctask

The problem I have is concerning two separate Asynctask classes. The first asynctask uses a network operation in doInBackground method

```
HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
```

while the other is a thread for loading images with a progressDialog.

so what happens is if I am using a slow internet connection (so that means the first asynctask hasn't finished yet) and then go directly to the second asynctask, the second class will wait until the first one is finished.

btw, right after I call the first asynctask I directly finish the activity and call another one does this have to do with anything?

tl;dr version:

second asynctask won't do the doinbackground process until the first asynctask is done

I know this because the progress dialog is shown for a long time (which I show it in preExecute and dismiss it in postexecute)

**EDIT:**

the first asynctask involves waiting for a response from the net. so while there isn't a response the second asynctask won't do its doinbackground process.

**EDIT 2:**

Is there a way for me to properly use these 2 asynctask so the second one won't have to wait for the first to finish?

Comment: Your post isn't very clear, and "second asynctask won't do the doinbackground process until the first asynctask is done" isn't a question.

Comment: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html. Go throught the link. You might find answer to your question.

Comment: I have 2 separate asynctask classes. what happened is that the second asynctask wont do its doinbackground method until the first asynctask which is a network operation is done. I guess I'm not too good at enplaning things

Comment: the progress dialog is shown for a long time. which means it did call the onpreExecute method and stopped at the doinBackground method

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had same problem in my app - i needed to run 4 AsyncTasks concurrently in any Android version (from 2.1 - to 4.2). But from Honeycomb, AsyncTasks run in serial.

So i had wrote AsyncTaskExecutor - it can runs AsyncTasks concurrently on any Android version.

Take a look:

### **[AsyncTaskExecutor](https://github.com/artem-zinnatullin/Android-AsyncTask-Executor)**

It takes all work for running AsyncTask concurrently on any Android OS version, it is better that using:

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB) {
    task.executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR);
} else {
    task.execute();
}
```

Because AsyncTask.THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR available only on api >= 11; I`m using own threadPoolExecutor instance

#### With AsyncTaskExecutor you just need to write:

```
AsyncTaskExecutor.executeConcurrently(task, params);
```

#### And that is all. No errors on Android 2.x, 3.x and 4.x

P.S. I am sorry for copying my answer from other question, but I think, it will be helpful

Answer (score 1):

Start second AsyncTask in First AsyncTask onPostExecute(String result) method then second AsyncTask is start after complete first AsyncTask.

Thanks

Comment: thanks for the reply. but the second asynctask is in a different activity

Comment: Second AsyncTask run from different android activity class?

Comment: If that could be implemented the result would be the same: the asynctasks would be run in serial.  I think that is not the desired behavior.

Answer (score 1):

Google changed behavior of AsyncTask in Honeycomb (3.0).  Now all the AsyncTask's of a process are run in serial - as you have observed.

This can certainly be a problem, as in the case you have described.  I think you will need to convert one of your asynctask's into something else, e.g. a Runnable.